# Should I pre-resize big UIImage before assigning to a UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

If I have a large UIImage that need to be displayed on a smaller UIImageView.Should I resize the image first or should I count on the `contentMode` of UIImageView?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the content mode as Scale To Fill maintaining the aspect ratio of UIImageView so that it may not feel like getting stretched.